# Upload file inside a folder with FilePond in MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller, filepond

I'm trying to use FilePond to upload files to my project. I want to keep the files inside of a file (Images/Banner). But When I add the class="filepond" inside the input variable , IFormFile returns null. Any idea how can I fix this ?

```
@model InputViewModel

<form method="post" asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file"
           class="filepond"
           name="postedFiles"
           multiple
           data-allow-reorder="true"
           data-max-file-size="3MB"
           data-max-files="3">

    <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" style="visibility:visible">Save</button>

</form>
```

Controller

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
    {
        private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _hostEnvironment;
        public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger,IWebHostEnvironment hostEnvironment)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _hostEnvironment = hostEnvironment;
        }

        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(InputViewModel command)
        {
               
            return View();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(InputViewModel command, List<IFormFile> postedFiles)
        {
            string wwwPath = this._hostEnvironment.WebRootPath;
            string contentPath = this._hostEnvironment.ContentRootPath;

            string path = Path.Combine(this._hostEnvironment.WebRootPath, @"images\banner");
            if (!Directory.Exists(path))
            {
                Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            }
            List<string> uploadedFiles = new List<string>();
            foreach (IFormFile postedFile in postedFiles)
            {
                string fileName = Path.GetFileName(postedFile.FileName);
                using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(path, fileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    postedFile.CopyTo(stream);
                    uploadedFiles.Add(fileName);
                    ViewBag.Message += string.Format("<b>{0}</b> uploaded.<br />", fileName);
                }
            }
            return View();
        }
```

Comment: Could you show the payload and response pls

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is a work demo, you can refer to it.

InputViewModel:

```
public class InputViewModel
    {
        public List<IFormFile> postedFiles { get; set; }
    }
```

HomeController:

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(InputViewModel command)
        {

            return View();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> Create(InputViewModel command, List<IFormFile> postedFiles)
        {
            ...
            return View();
        }
```

Create View:

```
@model InputViewModel

<form id="uploadform" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" asp-for="postedFiles" class="filepond" multiple  data-allow-reorder="true"
           data-max-file-size="3MB"
           data-max-files="3"/>
    <span asp-validation-for="postedFiles" />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/jquery-filepond/filepond.jquery.js"></script>
<link href="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://unpkg.com/filepond/dist/filepond.js"></script>

<script>
    $(document).ready(function(e){
pond = FilePond.create(
    document.querySelector('.filepond'), {
        allowMultiple: true,
        instantUpload: false,
        allowProcess: false
    });

$("#uploadform").submit(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var formdata = new FormData(this);
  // append FilePond files into the form data
  pondFiles = pond.getFiles();
  for (var i = 0; i < pondFiles.length; i++) {
      // append the blob file
      formdata.append('postedFiles', pondFiles[i].file);
  }

  $.ajax({
    url: "/Home/create",
    data: formdata,

    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    method:"post"

  });

})
});
</script>
```

result:

[image]